# webservice doesn't prompt for authentication when call thru client application in asp.net

Tags: web-services, authentication

I have created a web service with authentication mode="Windows"
Also Enabled windows authentication in IIS.so when this web service is run in IIS manager it prompts for authentication but when called this web service through web form on button click it doesn't prompt for authentication.Why?

I want on button click win authentication dialog box should come and allow to view webservice on successful authentication.